# test case giving errors: "Cannot find name require"

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, karma-mocha

I have installed mocha and chai to write test cases for node.js written in typescript

when ever i am running my test case (npm test) getting error as below
[image]

package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-register"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.14.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "mocha": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "babel":{
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  }
}
```

test file :

```
    "use strict"
/// <reference path="./typings/globals/chai/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./typings/globals/mocha/index.d.ts" />
require('babel-register')({
    presets: ['es2015']
});
import chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
// Import the Rectangle class.
let Rectangle = require('./src/db/util/MetricsResponseParser.js');

describe('DistanceDateMetricResponseParser', () => {
  describe('parseResponse', () => {
    let dateTimeMetrics;

    beforeEach(() => {
      dateTimeMetrics = new DistanceDateMetricResponseParser();
    });

    it('Parse Response method ', (done) => {
      // This will fail if "rectangle.width" does
      // not equal 10.
      expect(dateTimeMetrics.parseResponse()).to.equals(Object);
      done();

    });

  });
  });
```

I have also installed babel as it transpiles the code to ES5
 I dont understand the issue here

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you try with this syntax instead of require : import code from 'code' // or
import code = require('code')

Comment: You are mixing 2 different syntaxes. Either use `import chai from 'chai';` or `var chai = require('chai');`